# mathtools with mu = Illegal unit?

Tags: mathtools, units, unit-of-measure

I'm trying to change `medmuskip` while using `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

But this results in an error:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
                   m
l.3 \setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu}
```

Without mathtools, this works.

Why and what should I do to be able to change `medmuskip`?

Comment: Probably not really helpful, but if I put `\setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu}` before `\usepackage{mathtools}`, it works for me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With the usual definition, `\setlength{<parameter>}{<value>}` is just a wrapper for

```
<parameter>=<value>\relax
```

so

```
\setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu}
```

is legal, because it translates to

```
\medmuskip=0mu\relax
```

which is perfectly legal, as `\medmuskip` should be assigned values only in `mu` units (also `fil`, `fill` or `filll` units for the `plus` and `minus` parts).

However, when `calc` is loaded (it's required by `mathtools`), `\setlength` changes meaning and mu units are not allowed any more, because `calc` is oriented to standard lengths only.

There's not much you can do about it other than defining a wrapper yourself:

```
\newcommand{\setmuskip}[2]{#1=#2\relax}
```

and do

```
\setmuskip{\medmuskip}{0mu}
```

or, say

```
\setmuskip{\medmuskip}{4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu}
```

(which is the default).

Comment: Nice! So in this case, why not use only `\medmuskip=0mu\relax`? What is the advantage using a new command?

Comment: @Sigur Uniformity of syntax.

Comment: @egreg A minor detail, but `\medmuskip` is `4mu plus 2mu minus 4mu` by default (at least according to Section 11.1 in _Math mode – v. 2.47_).