# Why conflict between mathtools and Gonzalo's solution for auto-adjusting description environment?

Tags: math-mode, lists, description, calc

Gonzalo Medina provided [a nifty solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099/7922) to "[Automatically set description list `labelwidth` based on widest label?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130097/automatically-set-description-list-labelwidth-based-on-widest-label)." (The goal was to define a `description` environment where the item text is automatically indented to the width of the widest label.)

I could replicate its success on a standalone basis, but when I incorporated it into my standard set of packages, it no longer produced the desired results. By a process of elimination, I discovered that simply loading the `mathtools` package was sufficient to cause the problem.

I don't know where to begin to search for the conflict or a workaround, but I'm hoping someone with more experience, with `mathtools` in particular, would spot it quickly.

Below is the MWE, straight out of Gonzalo's solution, except that I've inserted a commented-out `\usepackage{mathtools}`. (I've experimented with the order of loading `mathtools` but nothing solved the problem.)

Without `mathtools`, the proper output looks like:
[image]

With `mathtools`, the improper output looks like:
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}
%\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength\widest
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{ldescription}{%
  \vbox{%
    \global\setlength\widest{0pt}%
    \def\item[##1]{%
      \settowidth\@tempdima{\textbf{##1}}%
      \ifdim\@tempdima>\widest\global\setlength\widest{\@tempdima}\fi%
    }%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}%
  }
  \begin{description}[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
    labelindent=0pt,
    labelwidth=\widest]
  \BODY
  \end{description}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A really really long label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A medium label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After loading the length `\widest` gets "reseted". This is not really triggered by `mathtools` but by `calc`, which gets loaded by `mathtools`, as explained in [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188221/121799). It is then easy to solve the problem: set the distance using `=` rather than `\setlength`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newlength\widest
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{ldescription}{%
  \vbox{%
    \global\widest=0pt%
    \def\item[##1]{%
      \settowidth\@tempdima{\textbf{##1}}%
      \ifdim\@tempdima>\widest\relax
      \global\widest=\@tempdima\fi%
    }%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}%
  }
  \begin{description}[
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
    labelindent=0pt,
    labelwidth=\widest]
  \BODY
  \end{description}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A really really long label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A medium label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I revised this answer quite a bit because I learned a lot from [egreg's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188221/121799). Imagine how much I could learn from egreg's question, if he had one. ;-)

Comment: Wow. Super answer; both very interesting. (I keep discovering, mostly negatively, that commands are redefining things I rely on without my knowledge!) And very helpful. This saves the enterprise just by changing a few characters.

Comment: @JimRatliff Thanks! I actually did not know any of this, so thanks a lot for this really nice question! (How did I get on track? I just added `\typeouts` at many positions of your/Gonzalo's code, which revealed that `\widest` got resetted. Then I did a google search with `site:tex.stackexchange.com mathtools setlength`, which lead me right to egregs answer. This kind of strategy, i.e. `\typeouts` and google searches with `site:tex.stackexchange.com`, can sometimes be useful.)