# Estimating the width of multiline text

Tags: enumitem, width

I am using a macro made by [user121799](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461060/142888) originated from [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099/142888) (The main code is given in the first link). The macro takes the label text of the `description` environment defined in enumitem package, calculates the width of the text, and adjusts `labelwidth` according to the width estimation, where `align=parleft` is added to the original code):

```
\newlength\widest
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{ldescription}{%
  \vbox{%
    \global\widest=0pt%
    \def\item[##1]{%
      \settowidth\@tempdima{\textbf{##1}}%
      \ifdim\@tempdima>\widest\relax
      \global\widest=\@tempdima\fi%
    }%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}%
  }
  \begin{description}[
    align=parleft,
    leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
    labelindent=0pt,
    labelwidth=\widest]
  \BODY
  \end{description}%
}
\makeatother
```

I am curious about the width estimation part:

```
\@tempdima{\textbf{##1}}
```

If the `##1` contains a manual linebreak, the code does not work correctly; it simply ignores `\\` macro, which can be seen by the following code:

```
\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\item[A really really long label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}

\begin{ldescription}
\item[Short] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\item[A really really\\ long label] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{ldescription}
```

What is the simplest way to estimate the width of a paragraph with linebreaks?

Comment: you do not need to estimate the width of a paragraph you know it in advance that it is `\hsize` (so initially `\textwidth`) linebreaking happens automatically to force all lines to that length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure the width of some text that possibly involves manual linebreaks, use a tabular not a paragraph (and definitely not an `\hbox`)

You can replace `##1` by `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}##1\end{tabular}`  in both cases.

Comment: You always save my day.  Thank you.