# \hbox containing an equation environment

Tags: equations, box

I have the code in which an equation environment is in `\hbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\hbox{
\begin{equation}
    F=ma
\end{equation}
}

\end{document}
```

But it throws multiple errors. What should I correct?

Edit:
`\hbox` is used in the code in [NewEnviron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/619008/142888). When I try to insert an equation environment in `\item`, the same errors occur.

Comment: Why not just remove the `\hbox`? What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: @Werner I use `\hbox` in the code: `\setbox0=\hbox{...}`.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `\setbox0=\hbox{...}` with `\setbox0=\vbox{...}`? (I will also confess to having no idea what it is that you want to achieve.)

Comment: Please show us a short example of complete document, where you use your `hbox`. Without seeing context of it use we can only (unsuccessful) guess how to help you.

Comment: @Zarko I added the link to the entire code.

Comment: As I see now, your question is duplicate to the question in the link. BTW, There is not complete (compilable) document but only fragment with definition.

Comment: In the context of the linked question, it makes no sense to use an `equation` environment, which by the way occupies the whole text width (besides being illegal in `\hbox`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have a vertical construct like an equation in an hbox you could use a vertical box (`\vbox` or better a latex construct using  `\vbox` such as `\parbox` or `minipage`).

Alternatively use inline math `\(...\)`  not a display construct.

Comment: I decided to use `\vbox`. Thank you.

Comment: @Hermis14 but it's hard to see what `\vbox` will do there that is useful, what is the use case?

Comment: The code provided in [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099/142888] uses `\hbox` in `\setbox0=\hbox{\BODY}`. But I don't know why he used it though he explained the reason. After I replace `\hbox` with `\vbox`, it works as I want.

Comment: @Hermis14 oh I guess so, it's just setting it and throwing it away so vbox is safer than hbox certainly